# Wamp Server Development /var/site.php

Tags: php, wampserver

I'm using eclipse and a private GIT repository and then WAMP Server on my local machine (Win 8.1). I have a PHP application that I'm trying to emulate on my local machine but an integral include file is "/var/site.php". I'm trying to setup an include_path in php.ini but I keep getting not found errors. My path locally is:

```
c:/users/xxxxxx/git/project/site.php
```

I'm trying

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path = ".:/var/:c:/users/xxxxxx/git/project/"
```

This doesn't work. I'm confused on whether to use UNIX or WINDOWS in php.ini. I'm getting:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/site.php' (include_path='.:/var/:c:/users/xxxxxx/git/project/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not surprising really, you are using a unix path statement and you are running on windows.

Edit your php.ini file ( using the wampmanager icon menus so you get the right file)

Find this section

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
```

And change the Windows path statement like so

```
include_path = ".;/var/;c:/users/xxxxxx/git/project/"
```

Basically the path statements seperator in UNIX is `:` but as windows uses the colon in the drive identifier i.e. `C:` windows uses the `;` semicolon as the seperator on a path statement. You just got the 2 mixed up.